# Datagridview doesnt show data in rows

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am currently working on project in which i have to display IP Configuration to user in VB.Net Application.

I am using DataGridView to display IP Config to user.

But problem is Datagridview doesnt display anything in its row at all.

[Image for proof](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0hff5qwyth9wkx/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

*Here is the code*

```
Public Sub MT_Validate_Msg(ByRef lbData() As Byte)
    Dim lsAddr(3) As String
    Dim lsMAC(5) As String
    Dim lstConfig As TCP_SER_Config
    If lbData.Length >= 256 Then
        'Check Header Footer and Response Size
        If lbData(0) = Asc("$") And lbData(1) = Asc("#") _
            And lbData(254) = Asc("<") And lbData(255) = Asc(">") _
            And lbData(2) = UDP_RESPONSE_SIZE And lbData(3) = 0 Then
            gnDevice_Search_Count += 1
            'MsgBox("Response Received")
            lsAddr(0) = lbData(7).ToString
            lsAddr(1) = lbData(9).ToString
            lsAddr(2) = lbData(11).ToString
            lsAddr(3) = lbData(13).ToString

            lstConfig.IP = String.Join(".", lsAddr)


            lsAddr(0) = lbData(15).ToString
            lsAddr(1) = lbData(17).ToString
            lsAddr(2) = lbData(19).ToString
            lsAddr(3) = lbData(21).ToString

            lstConfig.Subnet = String.Join(".", lsAddr)


            lsAddr(0) = lbData(23).ToString
            lsAddr(1) = lbData(25).ToString
            lsAddr(2) = lbData(27).ToString
            lsAddr(3) = lbData(29).ToString

            lstConfig.Gateway = String.Join(".", lsAddr)

            lstConfig.Alive_Time = lbData(31)

            lsMAC(0) = Hex(lbData(33)).ToString
            lsMAC(1) = Hex(lbData(34)).ToString
            lsMAC(2) = Hex(lbData(35)).ToString
            lsMAC(3) = Hex(lbData(36)).ToString
            lsMAC(4) = Hex(lbData(37)).ToString
            lsMAC(5) = Hex(lbData(38)).ToString

            lstConfig.MAC = String.Join("-", lsMAC)

            MT_FillGrid(lstConfig)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

   Public Sub MT_FillGrid(ByRef lstTCPConfig As TCP_SER_Config)
    Dim row As String() = New String() {gnDevice_Search_Count.ToString, lstTCPConfig.IP, lstTCPConfig.Subnet, _
                                        lstTCPConfig.Gateway, lstTCPConfig.Alive_Time.ToString, lstTCPConfig.MAC}
    GridDev_List.Rows.Add(row)
    row = New String() {"1", "192.168.0.100", "255.255.255.0", "255.255.255.255", "60", "22-0B-3C-2D-00-01"}
    GridDev_List.Rows.Add(row)
  End Sub
```

Expecting a result [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kiawa7y3vpj912r/Capture1.JPG?dl=0), Where i am going wrong in code ?

Comment: Were you expecting it to yield results?

Comment: Yes !! in my application i broadcast message on UDP and in response receive IP config. When i receive data i call MT_Validate_Msg Subroutine, if valid header footer is received then i extract Data and display it in Datagridview using MT_FillGrid subroutine.